# Unmarshalling a nested array of strings using JAX-RS (Jersey)

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, jax-rs

I am currently using JAX-RS in order to implement a client for a 3rd party REST API.  While I understand the basics of using POJOs and annotations for automatic marshalling and unmarshalling of JSON payloads, the following data structure returned by one API has me **completely** stumped:

```
{
    "requestId": 1,
    "members": [
        ["Jason"],
        ["Mike"],
        ["Andy"]
    ]
}
```

The closest solution I can think of (that doesn't work) is as follows:

```
class Membership {
  String requestId;
  List<Member> members;
  // No argument constructor, getters, setters, etc...
}

class Member {
  String name;
  // No argument constructor, getters, setters, etc...
}
```

I use the following JAX-RS `javax.ws.rs.client.SyncInvoker.get(Entity<?> entity, Class<T> responseType)` method to try and automatically map the response (described above) onto the `Membership` POJO.  The `List<String>` created as a result has correct size (same as number of members), but each String inside of it is `null`.

What mistake am I making in trying to map my POJO onto the received JSON response?

### Edit 1:

Other variants for `members` variable that I have tried include:

- `List<String> members;` - Correct list size, however all Strings are empty.
- `String[] members;` - Correct array size, however all Strings are empty.
- `List<List<String>> members;` - Correct outer list size, inner list has all empty Strings.
- `String[][] members;` - NPE. Full stack trace [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/753f07d705b11b10c7ac/raw/035dc2842bce694a062b1b20b802b86b13311e0a/error)

### Edit 2:

The Jersey code I am using to access the REST API and try to parse its response is:

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.*;

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(Logger.class);
WebTarget target = client.target(thirdParty.getUrl()).path("members.json").queryParam("token", thirdParty.getToken());
Builder builder = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
Membership response = builder.get(Membership.class);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(response.getMembers()));
```

Comment: What's your JSON provider? Moxy? Jackson? Other?

Comment: An external API. It will provide me JSON in the format I specified above. I am using Jersey 2.15 to marshall and unmarshall POJOs into JSON.

Comment: List<List<String>> is the correct way. (don't use array) what is your jackson version